# Identify which part of a Perl regular expression was used when finding a match in a string

Tags: regex, perl

## Background

Perl provides [all sorts of built-in variables to get bits of a string which matched a regular expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions) (*e.g.* `$MATCH`, `$&`, or `${^MATCH}` for the part of the string that matched the regex, `$PREMATCH`, `` $` ``, and `${^PREMATCH}` for the part of the string before the part that matched, etc).

### Question

Is there any way to get the *portion of the regular expression* which actually was used to match `$MATCH`?

### Example

For example, say I have

```
my $string = "gC rL Ht Ns B lR cG sN tH";
my $re = qr/\b(a|b|c)\b/i;
$string =~ $re;
print "${^PREMATCH}\n";
print "$&\n";
print "${^POSTMATCH}\n";
```

The output will be

```
gC rL Ht Ns 
B
 lR cG sN tH
```

#### Desired output

The part of the regex (`/\b(a|b|c)\b/i`) which matched the string was `b`, or perhaps more properly `\bb\b`, with the case-insensitive switch `i`. How can I get `b` (ideally) or `\bb\b`? I can't find any built-in variable which stores any part of the regex that matched, only parts of the string.

### Answer

Thanks to the great hint in [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba)'s answer, it seems that using [named capture groups](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3f'NAME'pattern)) and the [`%+` built-in variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25%2b) will work:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -e '
    "gC rL Ht Ns B lR cG sN tH" =~ /\b((?<a>a)|(?<b>b)|(?<c>c))\b/i;
    print Dumper keys %+;'
$VAR1 = 'b';
```

Comment: You are after `qr/\b$1\b/`. Just out of curiosity, why you need that?

Comment: I don't see how `qr/\b$1\b/` could possibly work. `$1` is set to the value of the _string_ which mached the regex. I need the reverse. I need the part of the _regex_ which was used to match the string.

Comment: To be nitpicking: `$1` also only contains the part of the string that was matched by the group, not which element of the pattern did match it. Of course, if there is no clear one-to-one relationship between the two, something is wrong with the pattern, just saying. But for example for statistics which part of a more complicated pattern (one where each possible element can match more than one thing) it might be useful to just store the matching part of the pattern, not part of the string. On the other side: It should definitely be possible to find the desired data from the contents of `$1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally not possible as regular expressions can be very complex. The string `bydgijjj` matches `(?:ax|by)[cd]*(ef|g[hi](?:j{2,}|klm))`, what would you like it to return? Can you imagine how complex it is?

You have to construct the regular expression in a way it will tell you:

```
"gC rL Ht Ns B lR cG sN tH" =~ /\b((a)|(b)|(c))\b/i;
print "a:$2\nb:$3\nc:$4\n"
```

Comment: Yes, I realise it could become very complex, very quickly. Your approach seems reasonable. Just find the group which is not `undef`. Probably using named groups, where the name is the (simple in my case) actual alternative, might work very well.

Comment: Following up on your proposal, [according to the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25%2b), _[t]he keys of the "%+" hash list only the names of buffers that have captured (and that are thus associated to defined values)._, so naming the capture groups to be the same as what they capture will probably work.